# Why the variable newP2Points is calculated differently than newP1Points?

Tags: scala, probability, figaro-lang

I try to understand the idea behind this code. The code elaborates the tennis model to model individual points as rallies.

A match of tennis consists of a number of sets, each of which consists of a number of games. The first player to win two sets wins the match. The first player to win six games wins a set. The first player to get four points wins the game, unless both players get to three points. In that case, the first player to move two points ahead of his opponent wins the game.

I understand the Figaro 's functions but some lines of code are confusing.

```
object TennisGame{
 def tennis( probP1ServeWin: Double, probP1Winner: Double, probP1Error: 
             Double,probP2ServeWin: Double, probP2Winner: Double, 
             probP2Error: Double): Element[Boolean] = {

  def rally(firstShot: Boolean, player1: Boolean): Element[Boolean] = {
     val pWinner = 
      if(firstShot && player1) probP1ServeWin //pWinner will be equal 
                                                //with probP1ServeWinif is 
                                                //the first shot for 
                                                //player1

      else if (firstShot && !player1) probP2ServeWin  
      else if (player1) probP1Winner 
      else probP2Winner
      val pError =if (player1) probP1Error else probP2Error
      val winner = Flip(pWinner)  //winner will be true with a 
                                   //probability equals with pWinner and 
                                  //false with a probability 1- pWinner

      val error = Flip(pError) 

         //With the probability = winner, Constant(player1) is chosen, 
        //producing  player1 with probability 1.0, while with probability
       //1 - winner, If(error, Constant(!player1), rally(false, !player1)) 
      //is chosen

  If(winner, Constant(player1), If(error, Constant(!player1),
  rally(false,!player1)))

    }


 def game(p1Serves: Boolean, p1Points: Element[Int], p2Points: 
          Element[Int]): Element[Boolean] = {

   val p1WinsPoint = rally(true, p1Serves)

    //Apply takes two arguments  p1WinsPoint and p1Points, the Apply’s 
   //function argument takes one Boolean and one integer named wins and 
   //points and calculate the score for player 1
   val newP1Points = Apply(p1WinsPoint, p1Points, (wins: Boolean, points: 
                           Int) => if(wins) points + 1 else points)
   val newP2Points = Apply(p1WinsPoint, p2Points, (wins: Boolean, points: 
                           Int) =>if(wins) points else points + 1)
   val p1WinsGame = Apply(newP1Points, newP2Points, (p1: Int, p2: Int) => 
                          p1 >= 4 && p1- p2 >=2)
   val p2WinsGame = Apply(newP2Points, newP1Points, (p2: Int, p1: Int) => 
                          p2 >= 4 && p2- p1 >=2)
   val gameOver = p1WinsGame || p2WinsGame

  If(gameOver, p1WinsGame, game(p1Serves, newP1Points, newP2Points))
 }

def play(p1Serves: Boolean, p1Sets: Element[Int], p2Sets: Element[Int], 
         p1Games: Element[Int], p2Games: Element[Int]):Element[Boolean] ={

 val p1WinsGame = game( p1Serves, Constant (0), Constant(0))
 val newP1Games = Apply(p1WinsGame, p1Games, p2Games, (wins: Boolean, 
                         p1:Int, p2: Int) =>                                
                         if(wins){
                                  if(p1 >= 5) 0 else p1 + 1 
                            }else
                            {
                                if(p2 >=5) 0 else p1
                            })
val newP2Games = Apply(p1WinsGame, p1Games, p2Games, (wins: Boolean, p1: 
                        Int, p2: Int) =>
                            if(wins){
                               if(p1 >= 5) 0 else p2
                            }else
                            {
                                if(p2 >=5) 0 else p2 + 1
                            })
val newP1Sets = Apply(p1WinsGame, p1Games, p1Sets, (wins: Boolean, games: 
                       Int, sets: Int) =>
                       if(wins && games == 5) sets + 1 else sets)

val newP2Sets = Apply(p1WinsGame, p2Games, p2Sets, (wins: Boolean, games: 
                      Int, sets: Int) =>
                     if(!wins && games == 5) sets + 1 else sets)

val matchOver = Apply(newP1Sets, newP2Sets, (p1: Int, p2: Int) => 
                     p1 >= 2 | p2 >= 2)
 If(matchOver, Apply(newP1Sets, (sets: Int) => sets >= 2), play(!p1Serves, 
    newP1Sets, newP2Sets,newP1Games, newP2Games))
   }   
   play(true, Constant(0), Constant(0), Constant(0), Constant(0)) 
 }

 def main(args: Array[String]){}
}
```